# jQuery получение параметра по id в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, mvc

Хочу получить текстовое содержимое по id, например получить "6000118":

```
<p id = "tst">6000118</p>
```

В методе jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getName() {
            $('#searchresult').load('@(Url.Action("nameMatResult", "Edit"))', { asd: Math.random(), code: $('#tst').get(0) },
                function () { setTimeout(getName, 2000) });
    }
    $(document).ready(function () { getName() });
</script>
```

Описание: Метод работает каждые 2 секунды и вызывает частичное представление с параметром code, которое вставляет в блок searchresult.

Частичное представление в контроллере Edit:

```
public ActionResult nameMatResult(string code)
    {
        ViewBag.nameMaterial = getNameMaterial(code);
        return PartialView();
    }
```

При этом всём используется jquery 1.9.1
Но ничего не работает, консоль сообщает:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>       at add (jquery-3.3.1.js:8463)
>       at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8450)
>       at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8444)
>       at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8444)
>       at buildParams (jquery-3.3.1.js:8444)
>       at Function.jQuery.param (jquery-3.3.1.js:8483)
>       at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.js:9073)
>       at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.load (jquery-3.3.1.js:9878)
>       at getName (Create?stove=1&date=10%2F07%2F2019 13%3A23%3A07:54)
>       at HTMLDocument. (Create?stove=1&date=10%2F07%2F2019 13%3A23%3A07:57)"

Если убрать чтение id, а именно $('#tst').get(0) и принудительно это заменить текстовым значением в кавычках, то всё работает прекрасно. В этой ситуации выходит, что используется два jquery - 1.9.1, который использую я и 3.3.1, который использует стандартный шаблон MVC, от которого отказываться не хотелось бы. Может быть есть какое-то решение на этот счёт? И не совсем понятно, почему метод в целом работает, а с чтением параметра по id нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так происходит потому что `get(0)` получает элемент в чистом js из объекта jQuery, а не значение внутри тегов! Используйте метод `text()` чтобы получить значение либо если Вы уж хотите использовать `get(0)`, то тогда получайте текст из чистого js

```js
console.log($('#tst').get(0));
console.log($('#tst').text());
console.log($('#tst').get(0).innerText);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id = "tst">6000118</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно работает. К сожалению, я слишком упростил вопрос, т.к. думал, что это будет аналогично, что к <p>, что к Html.EditorFor, но это оказалось не так. Я использую форму ввода Html.EditorFor(model => model.code, new { htmlAttributes = new { class = "form-control", id = "tst" } })  И предполагал, что введенные данные будут сразу обрабатываться, но в результате в контроллер в переменной string code пустая строка.